# How to render R stargazer output using rpy2 in ipython jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, stargazer

I wish to display a nicely formatted regression table in an ipython jupyter notebook. I use rpy2 to run regressions and collect output in stargazer for R. How can I render the table nicely in the notebook? I would like to have code that looked something like this:

```
%%R
summary(diamonds)
reg1 <- lm(price ~ carat, data=diamonds)
reg2 <- lm(price ~ carat + depth, data=diamonds)
display_html(stargazer(reg1, reg2))
```

Comment: My current workaround is to use the `huxtable` library function `export_summs` but it would be great to get stargazer working in this environment.

Answer (score 1):

Stargazer renders properly in jupyter notebooks with the option type = "text".

```
stargazer(reg1, reg2, type="text")
```